# understanding numpy np.tensordot

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array, tensordot

```
arr1 = np.arange(8).reshape(4, 2)
arr2 = np.arange(4, 12).reshape(2, 4)
ans=np.tensordot(arr1,arr2,axes=([1],[0]))
ans2=np.tensordot(arr1,arr2,axes=([0],[1]))
ans3 = np.tensordot(arr1,arr2, axes=([1,0],[0,1]))
```

I am trying to understand how this tensordot function work . I know that it returns the tensordot product.

but axes part is a little bit difficult for me to comprehend. what i have observed that

for ans  it is like the number of columns in array arr1 and the number of rows in arr2 makes the final matrix.

for ans2 it is the other way around number of columns in arr2 and number of rows in arr1

i dont understand axes=([1,0],[0,1]). let me know if my understanding for ans and ans2 is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to show the arrays:

```
In [87]: arr1
Out[87]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7]])
In [88]: arr2
Out[88]: 
array([[ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
In [89]: ans
Out[89]: 
array([[  8,   9,  10,  11],
       [ 32,  37,  42,  47],
       [ 56,  65,  74,  83],
       [ 80,  93, 106, 119]])
In [90]: ans2
Out[90]: 
array([[ 76, 124],
       [ 98, 162]])
In [91]: ans3
Out[91]: array(238)
```

`ans` is just the regular dot, matrix product:

```
In [92]: np.dot(arr1,arr2)
Out[92]: 
array([[  8,   9,  10,  11],
       [ 32,  37,  42,  47],
       [ 56,  65,  74,  83],
       [ 80,  93, 106, 119]])
```

The `dot` sum-of-products is performed on `([1],[0])` axis 1 of `arr1`, and axis 0 of `arr2` (the conventional across the columns, down the rows).  With 2d 'sum across ...' phrase can be confusing.  It's clearer when dealing with 1 or 3d arrays.   Here the matching size 2 dimensions are summed, leaving the (4,4).

`ans2` reverses them, summing on the 4's, producing a (2,2):

```
In [94]: np.dot(arr2,arr1)
Out[94]: 
array([[ 76,  98],
       [124, 162]])
```

`tensordot` has just transposed the 2 arrays and performed a regular `dot`:

```
In [95]: np.dot(arr1.T,arr2.T)
Out[95]: 
array([[ 76, 124],
       [ 98, 162]])
```

`ans3` is uses a transpose and reshape (`ravel`), to sum on both axes:

```
In [98]: np.dot(arr1.ravel(),arr2.T.ravel())
Out[98]: 238
```

In general, `tensordot` uses a mix of transpose and reshape to reduce the problem to a 2d `np.dot` problem.  It may then reshape and transpose the result.

I find the dimensions control of `einsum` to be clearer:

```
In [99]: np.einsum('ij,jk->ik',arr1,arr2)
Out[99]: 
array([[  8,   9,  10,  11],
       [ 32,  37,  42,  47],
       [ 56,  65,  74,  83],
       [ 80,  93, 106, 119]])
In [100]: np.einsum('ji,kj->ik',arr1,arr2)
Out[100]: 
array([[ 76, 124],
       [ 98, 162]])
In [101]: np.einsum('ij,ji',arr1,arr2)
Out[101]: 238
```

With the development of `einsum` and `matmul/@`, `tensordot` has become less necessary.  It's harder to understand, and doesn't have any speed or flexibility advantages.  Don't worry about understanding it.

`ans3` is the trace (sum of diagonal) of the other 2 ans:

```
In [103]: np.trace(ans)
Out[103]: 238
In [104]: np.trace(ans2)
Out[104]: 238
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand it from the tensordot documentation, you are supplying a list of axis in ans, ans2 and ans3 (ans and ans2 just only have one element in the list). This list then specifies which axes to summed over. You are right in you assumption of ans and ans2 where in ans your first element is the 0 axis of arr1 (rows in arr1) and the 1 axis in arr2 (the columns in arr2). I am not totally sure what to expect from ans3, but i might try running some examples myself and take a look. I hope this could give you a little better understanding

link: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html